# jQuery / JavaScript calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i make these calculations with jQuery / javascript?

Want the calculations to visible in the result div-tag

**height * width * thick * density**

```
<input type="text" id="hojd" /> * <input type="text" id="bredd" /> * <input type="text" id="tjock" /> * 

<select name="density" id="select">
    <option value="2,4">concrete</option>
    <option value="2,5">rock</option>
</select>
<br />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to acieve. Please elaborate

Comment: write a function that reads the size inputs and density input into variables, calculates the mass, and writes it to the result div. Call that function from an event handler for `change` on each of the inputs, including the select. you may need to use `2.4` for the density instead of `2,4`

Comment: You also might want to add a submit button so that you know when to read the fields.

Comment: You also need to provide your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would work if you change the commas in the select list to decimal points (javascript might assume the use of points for decimal separators). This does not contain any value validation, which I'll leave you to do yourself ;)

```
function calc() {
    var height = $('#hojd').val();
    var width = $('#bredd').val();
    var thick = $('#tjock').val();
    var density = $('#select').val();

    $('#result').html(height * width * thick * density);
}

$(function() {
    $('#hojd, #bredd, #tjock, #select').change(calc);
});
```

Edit:

Here's a working jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/84Hvr/2/

Comment: `parseInt()` will remove any decimal points, and it's not required for multiplications ;)

Comment: Well spotted. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It was fresh in my head after making myself look silly earlier and saying you *never* need to convert strings to numbers, and then someone pointed out `a + b`.  I felt like I'd never seen a computer before! :p

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 var output = $('#hojd').val() * $('#bredd').val() * $('#tjock').val() * $('#select').val();
```

Although, I'd assign a better ID name than 'select' to the drop down . . .

then

```
 $('#result').html(output);
```